# calling an object variable by using a string

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a function and I want to be able to pass in a string.  This string will be used to determine which object variable to access.  For example:

```
//passing in "name" variable as a function. 
//This will determine what object property 
//to use but I don't know how to do it.

var name = "firstName";
function myFunction(name) {
  var person={firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};

  console.log(person.name);  
//name is passed in as a string. 
// This is what I want to use to 
//determine which variable of "person" to use.  
}
```

I have already tried "person.name", "person.[name]", and "person.this.name".  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: `person[name]` without the dot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`person[name]` without the fullstop after person.

Comment: Better refer to a duplicate.